# Proper use of 'there'

Tags: adverbs

**There** is an adverb but in the following sentence as pronoun. 
 It first said he left the mission freely, contradicting Turkish media reports that he was murdered **in there**.
 Is this correct?

Comment: Looks correct to me!

Comment: The preposition is a little strange. I would either say "murdered in the mission" or just "murdered there." But "murdered in there" is unusual—unless it's said by somebody who's physically pointing at some place.

Comment: No, it's a preposition. "There" can be either a pronoun - the so-called 'dummy' pronoun, as in "_There_'s a fly in my soup", or a locative intransitive preposition, as in "Don't leave your shoes _there_". In your example it clearly belongs to the latter category.